# Unable to use fabric node sdk send transaction proposal to a multi-node network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, grpc

I have already set up a multiple node fabric network with 3 orderers, 4 peers. Besides, the chaincode has installed and initiated after running script.sh. Therefore the network is successfully set up.

Then I use node sdk with fabric-client interface to communicate with the network. However I meet this problem (error after send transaction proposal):
[image]

Comment: Add error messagge as text, not as image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set the timeout longer than now.